# How To Align Body Content so it Aligns w/Header & Footer

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am building a website but I started with a template and gutted it, changed a lot and got rid of the entire center section and now I have to start over with the body but whenever I try to insert the navigation menu, which is a javascript code that is inserted from another program I used to build it. Well, every time I try to insert the menu on the left side of the page, it falls outside the alignment of the header and footer, so instead of it being straight aligned with the header and footer on the left side, it is on the outside of where it should be. I'm absolutely retarded when it comes to this stuff so if someone could tell me the trick here and for building the content of the body. Just simple stuff like what html code and tags to use for making the boxes that you can insert things into, not image placeholders but boxes to input content like navigation menu or anything really?

HELP PLEASE.

here is the site.
Retairacket.thexdt.com

Comment: I would recommend learning the basics and see if that will help you... try w3schools.com

Comment: Site is down. Suspended at last check.

Answer (score 1):

I also get an invalid URL error.

By the sounds of your problem though, you should be able to fix it relatively quickly and easily. I assume from the sounds of it that your header and footer are a fixed width and that there is likely a fixed width block within the body that is forcing the body to be wider when you add in the (most likely) fixed width nav as well. If that's the case, then you will just need to change the way you are controlling the widths to suit the new nav bar. So reduce the width of one block to accomodate the width of the new one, make sense?

Remember, I haven't actually seen what the problem is, so I'm just guessing from your question here based on the most likely sceanario.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend learning the basics first. Designing a website isn't as everyone makes it out to be. As an extreme beginner without using WYSIWYG editors, coding HTML can be very complex. There aren't just "tags to use for making the boxes that you can insert things into."

Yes, there are `<p>` and `<div>` tags that will do what you want, but you need to understand what each tag does and when to use it.

I recommend the following sites:

- [w3schools](http://w3schools.com)
- [HTML Goodies](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3478131)
- [Webmonkey](http://webmonkey.com)
- [Search Google for "HTML basics"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=OJN&q=html+basics&btnG=Search)

Answer (score 0):

That URL isn't valid, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I also can't see your page, but I can see http://www.thexdt.com.  Is the design similar to that page?

That page uses tables for the general structure.  Is there is a large image or something bigger that the width of the external container?